# How to create columns from a column that contains several pieces of information?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a new dataframe by doing operations on two others and I would like to remove the false in the new dataframe but it is noted that my information is only in one column and I do not know how to do it.
[image]
code

```
import pandas as pd


 members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
 expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")

success_members_exp = pd.merge(members, 
expeditions[['expedition_id','termination_reason']], on='expedition_id', how='inner')
success_members_exp_pourcent["pourcent"] = success_members_exp.groupby('expedition_id')['success'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
success_members_exp_pourcent.to_frame()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
success_members_exp_pourcent["pourcent"] = success_members_exp.groupby('expedition_id')['success'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

to:

```
s = (success_members_exp.groupby('expedition_id')['success']
                        .value_counts(normalize=True)
                        .rename('pourcent')
                        .mul(100))
success_members_exp_pourcent = success_members_exp.join(s, on=['expedition_id','success'])
```

**Explanation**:

Output `s` is `Series with MultiIndex`, so for new column use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `rename` and multiple by `100`.

Comment: It gives this error : 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @UserCitron - Sorry, it is `success_members_exp`, not `success_members_exp_pourcent`

Answer (score 0):

Which column is your information stored in? What type of column is it? We are missing a lot of context, a print out of the column would be really nice, with a more specific explanation of what exactly you are trying to extract.

Comment: I have added a photo. I would like to remove the rows in the success column that have "False" in them